# Enter another value when it says error in Accees

Tags: ms-access, iif

I have IIf expression given below. Normally it works the way I want, but It gives an error when I do not enter appropriate numeric data. So, I want it to be blank or symbol, etc. when I do not enter a suitable value for the calculation. Many many thanks for your answers.

```
=IIf(Mid([EBGA];4;1)="/";IIf(Abs(Mid([EBGA];1;3)-400)>Abs(Mid([EBGA];5;3)-400);Format([KA1]/Mid([EBA1];InStr([EBA1];"/")+1;10);"Fixed");Format([KA1]/Mid([EBA1];1;InStr([EBA1];"/")-1);"Fixed"));Format([KA1]/[EBA1];"Fixed"))
```

Comment: Wrap it with `NZ` I think. `=NZ(your formula,"")`.

Comment: I try it but doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by 'not suitable'? If field is number type, it can only accept number or null, not alpha.

Answer (score 0):

If InStr() returns Null, Mid() will error because its position arguments must be numeric. If field used by InStr() is Null, InStr() returns Null. Handle possibility of Null.

`InStr(Nz([EBA1], ""), "/")`

Arithmetic with Null will return Null.